# Mac OS - make spotlight background transparent?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Is there a way to make the dropdown from Spotlight (eg "Suggested Sites") transparent?

More often than not I do simple calculations in Spotlight and I wanna see on the screen what values to put in. The background is blocking most of the view..

Answer (score 0):

No - you can reduce transparency, but not increase it.

You can drag the top or bottom edge to shrink it & if you drag it elsewhere on the screen it will remember that position.

This is how far I can reduce it on my screen [image intentionally small & blurry]

[image]

Comment: I have a rather small screen (13") so I don't have unlimited screen estate: I don't follow - how do I shrink it though. I can only move it around

Comment: Grab the top or bottom edge, when you see the cursor change to an arrow. [single headed, drag larger only, double-headed, drag larger or smaller]

Comment: I'm trying to hover over the spotlight in all corners / edges but no arrow appears. All I can do is drag the actual window around - no re sizing

Comment: It's there, it just may require more precision if you have a tiny screen & a trackpad to fumble with.